# DELETE using WHILE LOOP in a TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, transactions, sql-delete

I am trying to delete table which just has around 39K records, but for some reasons it is taking time(Around 1.5 minutes) even to delete a single record. How can I improve the performance of my delete operation. How can I ensure that log activity is not taking much time. Can I put the "DELETE" statement within a while loop and then open a transaction and commit it each time it successfully completes. Any other effective method is available?

[PrimaryKey] here has a "Clustered Index"

```
DECLARE @BatchCount INT;
SELECT @BatchCount  = COUNT(1) FROM #DHDID

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1

WHILE( @Counter <= @BatchCount)
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @ID INT;

SELECT @ID = DHDID FROM #DHDID WHERE ID = @Counter

DELETE FROM <MYTABLE> WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @ID

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

END
```

Comment: It shouldn't take more than a second or two to delete a single row even with a full scan of 39K rows. Index and/or query tuning can help optimize the delete query and avoid blocking. Add DDL and the query to your question if you need help with that.

Comment: Do you want to delete all the records from the table, or are you using the where clause to filter the records to delete?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Not deleting the entire table records but just part of it.

Comment: Show me your WHERE clause, paste the whole code.

Comment: If you table has a lot of recrods - for ex. milions and you want to filter the rows to deletion, then you might be missing an index on that column. Index may speed up the deletion operation.

Comment: Maybe you are missing an index on #DHDID.ID column with DHDID column in a leaf (include)? Assuming that for sure <MYTABLE> has a clustered index sorted by [PrimaryKey] column.

Comment: Can you also script the indexes you have on #DHDID and <MYTABLE>?

Comment: So, you're deleting from MyTable all the rows whose PrimaryKey matches the field DHDID in the temp table #DHDID?  Do I understand the purpose of the code you posted correctly?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz The #DHDID is not having any index but the [PrimaryKey] in <MYTABLE> has a clustered index.

Comment: @Brian Yes, you are correct.

Comment: How many rows are there in the #DHDID table?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Around 32K records

Comment: I am actually executing this in an "On premise" server. Could that be a reason?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer, you should do a set-based delete via a join.  Try something like this:

```
Begin Tran
Delete m
    From <MyTable> m
        Inner Join DHDID d
            on d.DHDID = m.[PrimaryKey]

-- error detection code here
If <an error occurred>
    Rollback
Else
    Commit
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a `TRY...CATCH` rather than trying to check if an error occured. Normally a statement is terminated when an error is reached, so you're `IF... ELSE` wouldn't be run.

Comment: I'd probably do that in a stored procedure, @Larnu, but in interactive code I doubt that I'd bother.  I'm old school :)

Comment: Why do you need to delete every single row in a transatcion?

Comment: I don't understand your question, @BartoszSiemasz - the code I posted does the entire delete as a single transaction.

Comment: @Brian - your code does it indeed, but not the code of Prakazz, I am asking him

Comment: Ahh - I couldn't tell that it was directed at someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I would try creating index on the #DHDID table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx] ON [#DHDID] ([ID] ASC) INCLUDE ([DHDID])
```

Comment: The suggested index (which could instead be clustered to avoid the included column), will avoid a full scan of the temp table for each loop iteration.

Comment: Without `UNIQUE`, SQL Server needs to read the next row during the index seek and scan operation before it knows all rows with the specified ID are read. Only one read is needed when SQL Server knows the value is unique. It's best to always specify unique for indexes unless the key is actually not unique.